# Ubuntu 17.04 customise login Gnome3 GDM

Tags: 17.04, gdm, gnome-shell

I'm using Gnome 3 on 17.04 and the default login screen is a basic gray background, and I'd like to customise it a bit to give it some color.

when I installed gnome 3, I picked GDM, but I can only find resources for lightdm. what I can find for GDM is not working or for an older version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know the [link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GDM#Log-in_screen_background_image) I provide isn't for ubuntu but it works the same way.
You need edit the `gnome-shell-theme.gresource.xml` file and set the background there, then recompile it with `glib-compile-resources`.